# Blazor Server not authenticating through windows

Tags: windows, authentication, server, blazor

I want a Blazor page that will automatically know who on my intranet is accessing the page.

I started a new Blazor Server (.Net 6) project and enabled Windows authentication.  I expected that when the page is accessed it would automatically know the user ID.  With no custom code added, I ran the project in VS.  When the browser loaded I got prompted for my credentials instead of the page just using my windows (active directory domain) credentials.  Entering my credentials into the prompt doesn't help, it just keeps asking.  I assume it's because it's not authenticating.  The settings in the launchSettings.json look right.  Anyone know why the authentication wouldn't work?

Update:
I was able to log in after I went into my browser settings and put http://localhost and https://localhost as sites that are allowed to show insecure content.  I don't automatically log in though.  I need to enter my credentials.

Comment: Do you still have anonymous access enabled?

Comment: @Lex No, windows authentication is enabled and anonymous access is disabled.